# Populating a worksheet /Revision

Tags: vba, excel

I having a problem on the code below. 
On row 130 i need to insert blank rows equal to the value in J. 
The code now is inserting blank rows equal to J but is starting on row J. I need to start on row k and then insert blank rows of J. How do I define the starting row and the number of blank rows?

```
70    j = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
80    k = 2
90    x = 1
100   Do While x < j
110       With ws2
120           If j > 0 Then
              'Insert J number of rows starting on row = k
130               .Rows(j).Resize(LastRow).Insert
140                   For i = 2 To rngtocopy.Rows.Count
150                       With ws2.Range("K" & k)
160                           .Offset(0, 0).Value = rngtocopy(i, 1)
170                           .Offset(0, 1).Value = rngtocopy(i, 2)
180                       End With
190                       k = k + 1
200                   Next i
210           End If
220       End With
230   x = x + 1
240   Loop
```

Comment: What do you want to do? I mean what is your question? Is there an error? If so, which line? Is it not producing your expected result? That maybe is the cause of the downvote.

Comment: I redefined the question.
in my code example if J=16 and K=2
then i want to insert 16 blank rows from the starting row of A2. If K=9 then I want to start on row A9 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but try this:

```
Set ws1 = Sheets("Calc")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Dealer Orders")

LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Set rngtocopy = ws1.Range("E2", ws1.Cells(LastRow, "F"))

For i = 1 To rngtocopy.Rows.Count
    With ws2.Range("K2")
        .Resize(, 2).Insert xlDown
        .Offset(-1, 0).Value = rngtocopy(i, 1)
        .Offset(-1, 1).Value = rngtocopy(i, 2)
    End With
Next
```

Is this somehow what you're trying? HTH.